# ckeditor assets directory gets removed when running cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am using ckeditor for a micro blog app and and every time i run `cap deploy` the ckditor directory gets removed. How can i fix this so that i can run cap deploy without removing my ckeditor assets directory on my vps server.

My deploy.rb is below.

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "whenever/capistrano"

server "xxx.xx.xx.xxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "cf"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:ramza1/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to copy directory with assets to shared path.
2. You have to create a symlink from release path using capistrano that points directory with ckeditor assets

Here is hat I do:

```
after "deploy:update_code" do
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
end
```

Comment: how will i copy the assets to the shared part first. cos if i do it your way, i will have an empty directory

Comment: should i create a task to run before deploy:update_cod and copy from the current_path to the shared_path the run the after deploy you have to copy from the shared path to the release path

Comment: Assets shouldn't be placed under version control, then after deploy there is no directory with assets in revision directory. You have to move your assets once manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Capistrano 3, add `public/ckeditor_assets` to the shared directory and add symbolic link :

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/ckeditor_assets}
```